# Reading from custom configuration section not working in .NET

Tags: .net, configuration

I'm trying to read in values from a custom configuration section in a .NET 4.0 app.  However, when inspecting the values they always display the defaults and not the custom values as I would expect.

Here's my class:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class TestSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("applicationAccessID", IsRequired = true)]
        public string ApplicationAccessID { get; set; }

        [ConfigurationProperty("username", IsRequired = true)]
        public Guid Username { get; set; }

        [ConfigurationProperty("password", IsRequired = true)]
        public Guid Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've added the following items to the config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="myCustomConfiguration">
      <section name="testSection" type="TestNamespace.TestSection,MyAssembly"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <myCustomConfiguration>
    <myAuthenticationSection applicationAccessID="1" username="9A36EC78-76B0-477B-9E36-613C13AE86BB" password="589A8696-2B9B-4ADD-906E-7245D387B594" />
  </myCustomConfiguration>
...
```

This line returns an instance of TestSection, but it's not reading the custom values from the config:

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myCustomConfiguration/myAuthenticationSection")
```

Any advice?

EDIT:
Here is my updated config file after removing groups:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="testSection" type="TestNamespace.TestSection,MyAssembly"/>
  </configSections>
  <myAuthenticationSection applicationAccessID="1" username="9A36EC78-76B0-477B-9E36-613C13AE86BB" password="589A8696-2B9B-4ADD-906E-7245D387B594" />
...
```

Same issue...

Answer (score 2):

You're using groups, so you need to implement a group handler too:

```
public class MySettingsConfigurationGroup : ConfigurationSectionGroup
{
}
```

There is lot more to it, take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx

Update:

```
public class TestSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static TestSection _testSection 
      = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TestSection") as TestSection;

    public static TestSection Settings
    {
      get
      {
        return _testSection;
      }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("applicationAccessID", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ApplicationAccessID { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("username", IsRequired = true)]
    public Guid Username { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("password", IsRequired = true)]
    public Guid Password { get; set; }

}

string id = TestSection.Settings.applicationAccessID;
```

Also, the name needs to match:

```
<testSection applicationAccessID="1" username="9A36EC78-76B0-477B-9E36-613C13AE86BB" password="589A8696-2B9B-4ADD-906E-7245D387B594" />
```

Comment: I took out the groups and am getting the same problem.  See additional code in OP.

Comment: I'm having the same issue when using your code.  The odd things is that when I purposely break something (using incorrect section name, etc.) I get a null when inspecting the result of ConfigurationManager.GetSection().  Now I'm getting an instance of TestSection with default values.

Comment: @MikeCole you need to call it using the static instance `TestSection LocalVariable = TestSection.Settings` and make sure the config file is correctly structured. It's because `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TestSection")` should only be called from the static instance when returning `_testSection` from `Settings`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this question is still valid, but anyway.

When dealing with `ConfigurationElement`s you need to address the issue that a configuration element is a collection of values, so you're **NOT** reading the values.

I'd replace for something like this:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("applicationAccessID", IsRequired = true)] 
public string ApplicationAccessID 
{ 
   get { return (string)this["applicationAccessID"]; } 
   set { this["applicationAccessID"] = value; }
} 

[ConfigurationProperty("username", IsRequired = true)] 
public Guid Username
{ 
   get { return (Guid)this["username"]; } 
   set { this["username"] = value; }
} 

[ConfigurationProperty("password", IsRequired = true)] 
public Guid Password 
{ 
   get { return (Guid)this["password"]; } 
   set { this["password"] = value; }
}
```